# ListPlot3D of data on "regular" lattice contained in an "irregular" region

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following problem when trying to plot some 3D data in Mathematica. The data are initially computed on a regular lattice, that is I compute

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x,y,f[x,y]},{x,x0,x1,dx},{y,y0,y1,dy}],1]
```

The problem is that `f` takes real values only in a non-convex subset `U` on the plane. `U` is actually quite nasty: a "triangular" region where all corners are cuspy (imagine the region in between three identical circles with any two of them tangent to each other). When I try to plot `data` with `ListPlot3D`, the latter plots a surface over the convex hull of `U`.

I was wondering if there is a way to tell Mathematica to restrict itself only inside `U`. I was thinking that since my points already lie on a "regular" lattice this should not be too difficult but I have not found yet a solution.

I am aware of the `RegionFunction` option but it is very expensive to compute in my case so I am trying to figure out a way that uses only the already computed points in `data`.

Comment: Could you just set values outside of U to 0? IE, something like g[x_,y_]=If[Chop[Im[f[x,y]]] == 0,f[x,y],0] and plot g[x,y] instead of f

Comment: This is possible to do, but it does not really help because then Mathematica joins the z=0 plane with the rest of the graph (with the part I want to draw). Perhaps there is a way to tell Mathematica to not connect these two parts?

Comment: How about "RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Chop[Im[f[x, y]]] == 0]"? BTW, I have better experience getting useful answers when I post Mathematica code that people can run themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a really nice picture, without using zillions of points, you might want to use a non-uniform distribution of points that includes the boundary of the region you want.  Here's an example somewhat like what you describe.  We start with three mutually tangent circles.

```
circPic = Graphics[{Circle[{0, Sqrt[3]}, 1],
  Circle[{-1, 0}, 1], Circle[{1, 0}, 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We write a Boolean function that determines whether a point in the rectangle {-1/2,1/2} by {0,Sqrt[3]/2} lies outside of all the circles and use this to generate some points in the region of interest.

```
inRegionQ[p:{x_, y_}] := Norm[p - {1, 0}] > 1 &&
  Norm[p + {1, 0}] > 1 && Norm[p - {0, Sqrt[3]}] > 1;
rectPoints = N[Flatten[Table[{x, y},
  {x, -1/2, 1/2, 0.02}, {y, 0.05, Sqrt[3]/2, 0.02}], 1]];
regionPoints = Select[rectPoints, inRegionQ];
```

Now we generate the boundary.  The parameter n determines how many points we place on the boundary.

```
n = 120;
boundary = N[Join[
  Table[{1 - Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/n, Pi/3, Pi/n}],
  Table[{Cos[t], Sqrt[3] - Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/3 + Pi/n, 2 Pi/3, Pi/n}],
  Table[{Cos[t] - 1, Sin[t]}, {t, Pi/3 - Pi/n, 0, -Pi/n}]]];
points = Join[boundary, regionPoints];
```

Let's take a look.

```
Show[circPic, Graphics[Point[points]],
  PlotRange -> {{-3/4, 3/4}, {-0.3, 1.3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we define a function and use `ListPlot3D` to try to plot it.

```
f[x_, y_] := -(1 - Norm[{x - 1, y}]) (1 - Norm[{x + 1, y}])*
  (1 - Norm[{x, y - Sqrt[3]}]);
points3D = {#[[1]], #[[2]], f[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ points;
pic = ListPlot3D[points3D, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Somehow, we've got to delete that stuff that lies outside the region.  In this particular example, we can use the fact that the function is zero on the boundary.

```
DeleteCases[Normal[pic], Polygon[{
  {x1_, y1_, z1_?(Abs[#] < 1/10.0^6 &)},
  {x2_, y2_, z2_?(Abs[#] < 1/10.0^6 &)},
  {x3_, y3_, z3_?(Abs[#] < 1/10.0^6 &)}}, ___],
  Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Pretty good, but there are a couple of problems near the cusps and it's definitely not very general since it used a specific property of the function.  If you examine the structure of pic, you'll find that it contains a `GraphicsComplex` and the first n points in the first argument of that `GraphicsComplex` is exactly the boundary.  Here's proof:

```
Most /@ pic[[1, 1, 1 ;; n]] == boundary
```

Now the boundary comes in three components and we want to delete any triangle that is formed by points chosen from just one of those components.  The following code does this.  Note that boundaryComponents contains the indices of those points that form the boundary and someSubsetQ[A,Bs] returns true if A is a subset of any one of the Bs.  We want to delete those triangle indices in the multi-Polygon that are subsets of one of the boundaryComponents.  That's accomplished in the following code by the `DeleteCases` command.

Oh, and let's add some decoration, too.

```
subsetQ[A_, B_] := Complement[A, B] == {};
someSubsetQ[A_, Bs_] := Or @@ Map[subsetQ[A, #] &, Bs];
boundaryComponents = Partition[Prepend[Range[n], n], 1 + n/3, n/3];
Show[pic /. Polygon[triangles_] :> {EdgeForm[Opacity[0.3]],
  Polygon[DeleteCases[triangles, _?(someSubsetQ[#, boundaryComponents] &)]]},
Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[Table[Append[pt, 0],
  {pt, Prepend[boundary, Last[boundary]]}]]}]]
```

Comment: +10 if I could. Not only solves the problem, but also provides a wonderful insight into Mathematica graphics. I learned a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the optimal solution, so I will keep the question open in case someone has a better idea.

Here is how I solved the problem I described in my question. First, I replaced points `{x,y,f[x,y]}` in `data` for which `f[x,y]` was complex by `{x,y,None}`. Then the following function creates a 3D surface out of my data points. Note here that `data` is the result of

```
data = Table[{x,y,f[x,y]},{x,x0,x1,dx},{y,y0,y1,dy}]
```

that is, no flattening (which works better for the following function). The function is:

```
makeSurface[data_] := Module[{len1, len2, polys, a, b, c, d, p},
  len1 = Length[data];
  len2 = Length[data[[1]]];
  polys = Table[
    a = data[[i, j]];
    b = data[[i + 1, j]];
    c = data[[i + 1, j + 1]];
    d = data[[i, j + 1]];
    p = Select[{a, b, c, d}, #[[3]] =!= None &];
    If[Length[p] >= 2, Polygon[p], None],
    {i, 1, len1 - 1}, {j, 1, len2 - 1}];
  Graphics3D[Join[{EdgeForm[None],FaceForm[Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]]]},
    Select[Flatten[polys, 1], # =!= None &]]]]
```

The above code can be probably optimized but it worked well enough for me.